# wrong output in matching elements of a list of list in python

Tags: python, list

I have a list of list in python whose sample data looks like this:

```
list_of_list = = [['AB2768', 'New York City', '25.0'], ['AB1789', 'San Francisco', '38.0'], ['AB6783', 'Chicago', '7.0'], ['AB2897', 'New York City', '30.0']]
```

What I have is that I am passing two parameters to my function - `id`, `city`. In my function I am matching if bot the parameters match then return the third value else return `0`. Here is my code so far:

```
def match_records(id, city):
    list_of_list = [['AB2768', 'New York City', '25.0'], ['AB1789', 'San Francisco', '38.0'], ['AB6783', 'Chicago', '7.0'],['AB2897', 'New York City', '30.0']]


    enrollment = ''

    print("searching for id- " + str(id))
    print("searching for city- " + str(city))
    for idnum, cityname, val in list_of_list:
        print(idnum + ', ' + cityname + ', ' + val)
        if str(idnum.strip()) != '' and str(id.lower().strip()) != str(idnum.lower().strip()) and str(
                city.lower().strip()) not in str(cityname.lower().strip()):
            print('either id is empty or id not found or city not found')
            flag = 1

        else:
            print('Found a mactch')
            flag = 0
            enrollment = val
            break

    return (flag == 0, enrollment)
```

If I do `print(match_records('AB2768', 'San Francisco'))` the ideally I should get `False` as `AB2768` and `San Francisco` are not in same list but I am getting `True`. In fact if either of the two inputs are correct its returning `True`. I know the error is somewhere in my `if` logic but I am unable to guess what it is. What is the mistake here?

Comment: Make sure you reproduce your indentation properly when posting Python code. Otherwise you are introducing new problems into the code.

Comment: Using `dict` with a 2-tuple as the key would make more sense here... (especially for repeated lookups)

Comment: @khelwood I have updated my post above for proper formatting. I didn't noticed it earlier when I posted it.

Comment: @JonClements The `list_of_list` is something that's getting generated by some other part of the code which I cannot change.

Comment: @user2916886 that's fine - are you searching the list as a once off or are you going to want to search it more than once...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use "truthy" statements in the code:

```
def match_records(id, city):
    list_of_list = [['AB2768', 'New York City', '25.0'], ['AB1789', 'San Francisco', '38.0'], ['AB6783', 'Chicago', '7.0'], ['AB2897', 'New York City', '30.0']]

    new_list = [i for i in list_of_list if id in i and any(city in b for b in i)]
    if new_list:
          return new_list[0][-1]
    else:
          return 0


print(match_records('AB2768', 'San Francisco'))
```

In this example, the code looks for any of the sublists that contain both the id and the city. However, if both are not found in the same sublist, the sublist will not be added to the enter list in the comprehension. Thus, if no match is found, an empty list will be created. In Python, an empty list evaluates to `False`, so returning its boolean will give `False`.

Comment: with this is if I have New York as input parameter then also it will return false. In my code above I was matching for substring using `not in` so that even if New York comes it will match it. Also how is it returning the 3rd value if the id and city match?

Comment: @user2916886 Thank you for clarifying. I have edited my answer.